# Start python script with information containing message directly from messenger API in a safe way

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, facebook-messenger-bot

My network configuration: I have a revers proxy nginx handling https behind it will be a golang server (gs). 
I want gs to run my python script with the data that comes in as JSON with the POST at `/webhook`. 

I Thought about using `sys.args` but I am not sure is it, or how to make it safe. Is there an injection attack possible? 
My plan was to make gs parse the JSON and run:

```
python3 respond.py -txt "this is message sent from messenger" -mid 0000000000 -pld "payload if a button was pressed"
```

Python would create message and sent it to facebook by it self, so it would have to be called for every messsage. The traffic isn't big but still if there is a best solution I would like to find it. 

Other thing that I considered was to run python3 listening on a port and forward to it raw incoming JSON over tcp (JSON that golang server recieves).

Answer (score -1):

Does the Script have to run often or only with some requests?
If yes, consider implementing a pipe between the processes and have the python script listen for incomming messages via the pipe.

Comment: Can you explain what should to do if your question(in the first line) is `false`?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'd just have the Server call the os to execute the python script with the given arguments.